# Proof of square-free polynomial factorization over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

Why should it be that the greatest common divisor of a polynomial and it's derivative produce the product of the repeated factors?

What about the case where the derivative is zero in $\mathbb{F}_p$? Why does the approach continue to work in this case?

This is considered a trivial step in most algorithms, and that may be the case, but I'm having trouble finding a proof of the correctness of the basic algorithm [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Square-free_factorization).

A proof that $f / \gcd(f,f')$ eliminates repeated factors would be appreciated.

Comment: @reuns that is not true, if $f' = 0$ then $(f',f) = f$.

Comment: Of course, a typo

Answer (score 2):

If $f = q^k g$ where $q \nmid g$ and $q$ is irreducible then

$$ f' = k q' q^{k-1} g+ q^k g'$$

so the highest power of $q$ dividing $f'$ is $k-1$ (it is not difficult to show that if $q$ is irreducible then $(q,q')= 1$).

So dividing by $(f,f')$ is dividing by every irreducible factor to one power less than what appears in $f$.

EDIT: proof of $(q,q') = 1$ in the finite field case

If $q' \neq 0$ we are done because $q$ is irreducible.

If $q' = 0$, $q = \sum a_i x^{pk}$ where $p$ is the characteristic of our finite field $k$.

Note that $q(x+y) = q(x) + q(y)$. If $q(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in k$, then $(x-x_0) | q$, contradicting irreducibility of $q$.

Then, by pigeonhole, $q(x_0) = q(y_0)$ for some $x_0, y_0 \in k$. However, then $q(x_0 - y_0) = 0$, reaching a contradiction again.

Comment: Otherwise good stuff, but I think there is a problem in your argument for the implication "$q'=0$ $\implies$ $q$ reducible". For $q(x+y)=q(x)+q(y)$ to hold for all $x,y$ you need A) $q(0)=0$, B) only terms of degree that are *powers* of $p$ as opposed to *multiples* of $p$, right? The usual argument is to use the fact that a finite field is perfect, and deduce that $q=f^p$ for a certain lower degree polynomial whenever $q'=0$.

Comment: For example with $p=3$, $q(x)=x^6$ we do have $q'=0$ but 
$$q(x+y)=(x+y)^6=((x+y)^2)^3=(x^2+2xy+y^2)^3=x^6+2x^3y^3+y^6\neq q(x)+q(y).$$

Answer (score 1):

In characteristic $p$ there is a subtlety with things like $f=x^p(x-1)$ which gives $f' = x^p=\gcd(f,f')$.

In general factoring in irreducibles $f=\prod_j h_j^{e_j}$ we'll have $\gcd(f,f')=(\prod_{j,p\ \nmid\ e_j} h_j^{e_j-1})(\prod_{j,p\ |\ e_j} h_j^{e_j})$, this follows from $f' = \sum_j e_j h_j^{e_j-1} \prod_{i\ne j} h_i^{e_i}$ and $\gcd(f,f')=\prod_j h_j^{d_j}$ for some $d_j$ (as $\gcd(f',f)$ divides $f$).